# How to unlist a vector [1:3] in R?

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a vector which has "lists" inside, it appears as it has 3 elements (as it was a list).
This is how it looks:
[image: image 1]

When you type `str(my_complete_vector)` you get that is a vector not a list of lists.

```
str(my_complete_vector)
 chr [1:3] "SIGLEC14, TOM1, LOC102725035, CRISP3, VAT1, ATG7, AGPAT2, OLFM4, LOC107987462, CEACAM3, HPSE, CEACAM8, RAB10, C"| __truncated__ ...
```

However, I need a vector [1:1] and I don't know how can I get it (note that some genes are repeated, so I would like to remove them if they are already saved).

I have tried with a for loop, to fill a new vector, but it doesn't work, because it gets the same form.

This is a reproducible example:

```
library(ReactomePA)
genes <- c("100049587","10008","10010","10011","100113407","100144748","10024","10043",
           "10112","10154","10170","10184","101927057","10221","10226","10237",
           "10254","10272","102725035","10287","10308","1031","10317","10321",
           "1033","10346","10367","10403","10410","10411","10451","10459",
           "10461","10493","10509","1052","10533","10538","10553","10555",
           "10558","10561","10562","10573","10581","10589","10602","10615",
           "10616","10627","1063","10643","10673","107080638","1071","10745",
           "10791","10797","107987425","107987462","10802","1084","10855","1088",
           "1089","10890","10912","10960","10964","10970","10991","11004",
           "11006","11025","11035","11065","111089941","1111","11130","11138",
           "11170","1118","11189","11213","11237","112950","113130","11316",
           "11326","113278","11328","113402","1135","1141","1147","114769",
           "114883","115761","116092","1163","116328","116369","1164","117581",
           "118788","118932","1192","1200","121512","122402","122553","122953",
           "1230","1241","124460","126014","127396","128346","128646","131540",
           "132321","132864","133","1349","135114","1355","136259","1378",
           "1390","140739","140823","143","1432","143503","143689","144423",
           "1453","146223","1475","148","148362","149483","150165","150290",
           "1509","152007","1535","1536","1545","154664","157313","158293",
           "158405","158747","1588","1622","1627","1649","166012","167555",
           "168455","170689","1718","1719","1730","1738","1796","182",
           "1820","1843","1845","1861","1871","1889","1890","19",
           "1910","1955","1956","196394","196410","196883","197259","200010",
           "200734","2012",  "201294","203228","2046",  "206358","2078",  "211",  
           "2120",  "2123",  "2131",  "2153",  "2171",  "2180",  "2181",  "2185", 
           "219285","219988","2200",  "220134","2204",  "2207",  "2209",  "220929",   
           "221",   "221002","221035","221079","221178","221421","221692","222234",   
           "222235","222389","2242",  "2258",  "2264",  "2268",  "22797", "22849",
           "22856", "22862", "22895", "22898", "22904", "22921", "22928", "22936",
           "22941", "22944", "22949", "22974", "22978", "23001", "23080", "23095",
           "23105", "23166", "23179", "23218", "2322",  "23250", "23254", "23313",
           "23315", "23317", "23385", "23397", "23401", "23424", "23446", "23498",
           "23564", "23569", "2358",  "23593", "23597", "23601", "23643", "23673",
           "23765", "240",   "241",   "246329","2526",  "2529",  "255738","255809",   
           "255919","257019","25797", "25798", "25805", "2581",  "2584",  "25886",
           "25907", "2591",  "259266","25934", "2597",  "25979", "26010", "26092",
           "26099", "26112", "26118", "2621","26234", "26251", "26253", "26270",
           "2629","26511", "26521", "26524", "26577", "26578", "26873", "26996",
           "27124", "27180", "27247", "27249", "27338", "27348", "2745","2760", 
           "2769","2787","2799","2820","28231", "2840","284021","284996" ,  
           "2850","285362","285533","285550","285590","285848","286053","2865", 
           "2867","28956", "2896","29089", "29097", "29110", "29126", "29128",
           "2919","2959","29796", "29916", "2992","29968", "30",  "3000", 
           "306", "3071","3087","3101","3140","3148","3149","3161", 
           "317", "317649","3240","3242","3301","332", "3340","3382", 
           "338339","338692","339487","340120","3417","3429","3430","3460", 
           "347735","3485","3490","353189","353345","3557","3586","3606", 
           "3624","3640","3656","3665","3679","3684","3687","37", 
           "3717","374907","375061","3753","375686","3772","3778","378",
           "3799","383", "3832","3833","387103","3872","387755","388121",   
           "3915","3930","3934","3939","3949","3956","3964","3984", 
           "3985","399823","4001","4005","4007","400793","401152","4013", 
           "4057","4070","4082","4084","4097","4116","414", "415116",  
           "4158","4192","4238","4257","4288","4317","4318","4327", 
           "433", "4353","4359","440068","440603","441864","4486","4520",
           "4605", "4607", "4615", "4616", "4647", "4651", "4671", "4680",
           "4683", "4689", "4694", "4709", "4751", "4783", "4807", "4837",
           "4893", "4923", "4973", "4974", "4987", "5005", "5008", "5023",
           "50486","5077", "51009","51053","51085","51097","5110", "51100",
           "51103","51141","51162","51207","51228","51246","51255","51256",
           "51282","5129", "51292","51299","51314","51316","51338","51371",
           "5138", "51439","51465","51510","5153", "51657","51659","51700",
           "51733","51734","51762","5209", "5218", "5223", "5226", "5236",
           "5271", "5294", "5321", "5328", "53346","5337", "535",  "5351",
           "5355", "5359", "5371", "53831","53918","54432","54437","5444",
           "54443","54464","54503","54516","54520","54620","54622","54676",
           "5468", "54682","54751","54757","54809","54863","54875","54897",
           "54961","54968","54981","54998","55004","5509", "55106","55122",
           "55129","5514", "55165","55191","55207","55217","55233","5525",
           "55255","55277","55288","55293","55314","55331","55332","55355",
           "55356","55357","55388","55454","55505","55635","55636","5564",
           "55640","55647","55741","55784","5580", "55856","55858","55884",
           "55888","55902","55911","5603", "5608", "5610", "5654", "5657",
           "566",  "5663", "56670","56829","5685", "56850","5688", "56913",
           "56945","57085","571",  "5710", "57126","5728", "5737", "57512",
           "57520","57538","57568","57572","57622","57633","57688","57706",
           "57826","5794", "5799", "580",  "5806", "58160","58480","58484",
           "58528","586",  "5861", "5888", "5925", "5932", "59342","59345",
           "597",  "5998", "6004", "6016", "6035", "6036", "604",  "6041",
           "60675","6238", "6241", "6272", "6277", "6279", "6283", "6303",
           "6320", "6324", "633",  "634",  "63876","6388", "6390", "63908",
           "63916","6402", "64067","64072","64078","64101","64151","64218",
           "64231","64342","64343","64374","64422","645455","64651","64778",
           "6484", "64859","6503", "6507", "6518", "653319","6543", "6548",
           "6556", "6582", "660",  "6604", "6672", "6688", "671",  "672", 
           "6732", "6768", "6788", "6790", "6809", "683",  "6854", "6945",
           "6947", "6948", "699",  "6993", "7018", "7033", "7046", "7075",
           "7077", "7083", "7084", "7097", "7099", "7100", "712",  "713")


yy = as.data.frame(enrichPathway(genes, pvalueCutoff=0.05, readable=T))

my_genes <- yy$geneID


my_complete_vector <- c()
for(i in 1:length(my_genes)){
  mylist <- my_genes[i]
  mylist <- gsub('/', ', ', mylist)
  my_complete_vector <- c(my_complete_vector, mylist)
}
```

Does anyone know how to help me?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: what do you mean by you need `vector [1:1]`?? does that mean you want `"SIGLEC14"`??

Comment: It looks like a `character` vector instead of a `list`.  If you want to extract individual elements from character vector, use `strsplit(my_complete_vector, ",\\s+")` and then `unlist`

Comment: I know that is a character vector, but it has several entries. As you can see there are characters save in [1] and characters in [2] and [3]. I want to join all of them, not to have [1], [2] and [3]

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself okay

Comment: Use the `strsplit` fucntion as indicated by akrun. or if you want it in a matrix notation you could do `a <- read.csv(text = my_complete_vector, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)` then you could do `a[1,1]` to get the first element

Comment: Yes, that it what I needed to do, thanks very much!

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates, you have several options. Once you convert it into a single list, you can convert it to a set in R using as.set(x) where x is your list if you don't care about the order. Or, you can use the function 'duplicated' to get the indices of duplicates and then remove them